# Apns: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I have a Java app, which works with Apple Push Notification Server (APNS). I use lib: **JavaPNS.jar** for sendings push messages to iDevices. 
But, sometimes Push Notification doesn't work, I've found such error:

> [16:35:40] Andrew Balakhanov: 2012-10-27 04:00:00,616 WARN 
>   [com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl] Failed to send message
>   com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@af310b99... trying again
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host  at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:44)
>   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:58)  at
>   com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:161)
>   at
>   com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
>   at
>   com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
>   at
>   com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
>   at com.clinics.core.api.util.APN.sendReminderAlert(APN.java:55)  at
>   com.clinics.core.api.services.schedule.reminder.impl.ReminderSenderMobile.prepareAndSend(ReminderSenderMobile.java:190)
>   at
>   com.clinics.core.api.services.schedule.reminder.impl.ReminderSenderMobile.send(ReminderSenderMobile.java:132)
>   at
>   com.clinics.core.api.services.schedule.reminder.AbstractReminderFacade.generateAndSendReports(AbstractReminderFacade.java:53)
>   at
>   com.clinics.core.api.services.schedule.reminder.ReminderJob.doIt(ReminderJob.java:64)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273) 
>   at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
>   at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
>   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)  at
>   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)

Could you please tell me, what the error means? Is it mean, that Apple server banned me, is it mean that I send too many requests to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely cause of this error is that you are sending production tokens to the sandbox server or sandbox tokens to the production server.

I got this exact behavior today until I figured out I had signed my app with an Ad Hoc profile, which makes the app use the production push server for generating the token, while my server was talking to the sandbox push server.

Comment: Now I get the same Exception, but I can get push message too. Do you know how to solve this problem? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This error could also appear when the payload is too long.

You can check by calling `PayloadBuilder`'s `isTooLong()` function.

```
PayloadBuilder payload = APNS.newPayload();

// build your payload               

if (payload.isTooLong())
{
    // your payload is too long, a push() will result in the above exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing was that the instructions I was using to generate my `.p12` certificate file were incorrect. I ended up following the instructions from [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) and those worked for me.